# Symbols being replaced on mobile email

Tags: email, unicode, symbols, emoji, checkmark

I'm trying to use the "✔" symbol in an email. When sent to iPhones and iPads it appears as a custom black checkmark emoji. This would be okay, but I am trying to have the checkmark appear blue.

Desktop: [image] (with additional black box)

Mobile: [image]

The solution is to specify the font 'dingbats':

```
<span style="font-family:dingbats, arial unicode ms, code2000, sans-serif;">&#10004;</span>
```

Comment: replace the black with a blue one in the resource files? What is the problem exactly? What have you tried? How is this a programming question?

Comment: This is in html/css. The checkmark, which is a text character that can have text attributes such as color, is being replaced by an Apple checkmark symbol that cannot have attributes such as color altered.